# Making lex/yaac script multhreaded

Tags: yacc, lex

I have a lex/yaac code which captures some data after parsing an file. That file is in specific format. Consider this format:

File format:

```
ABC
  Something something
ABC
  Something something
....
....
```

Lex/Yacc code is sequential right now. Is it possible to make the code multithreading for single file by dividing it into chunks separated by ABC.

Where to start?

I shall be happy to share more details, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't know where the delimiters are until you lexically analyse the file. Unless the delimiters are contextually unambiguous (which won't be the case if your syntax includes things like comments or quoted strings), then you can't start the analysis at a random point in the file without knowing the context of that point. So in common cases, finding the delimiters requires a linear scan.

You could hand a chunk of the file to a separate chunk parser thread every time you identify the chunk's endpoints. That will require scanning the chunk twice (once for the initial delimiter scan and a second time for the precise parse) but it might still be a win if parsing is relatively slow. You could avoid the second scan by retaining the token stream in memory and passing the parser thread the list of tokens, but it may well turn out that the memory management and other bookkeeping for the token lists are as or more expensive than the lexical scan. That will depend on a lot of factors, so experimentation and benchmarking in your particular use case will be necessary.

If the delimiters are completely unambiguous and the chunks are relatively short, you could divide the files into pages of some convenient size, and give each thread its own pages to analyse. When the thread is assigned a page, it will have to skip initial data until it finds the first delimiter; when it reaches the end of the page, it will have to continue scanning the rest of the current chunk in the next page. So there will be a bit of duplicate scanning, but if the chunks are short relative to the page size, it won't be too bad. Again, benchmarking your particular use case will be useful. And, again, you can only do this if you can unambiguously recognise a delimiter without knowing anything about the lexical context.